# Keep getting this Segmentation Fault :11 error

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, multidimensional-array, error-handling

I keep gettin this error on my code. My program was running perfectly just a few minutes ago and all of a sudden it kept throwing this error at me. I tried to find the error by using `cout << "here" << endl` in between some lines and sometimes it usually stops within my `for` loop inside the `readInName()` functions. Sometimes it would fully run and print out everything even the `"here"`. Other times i would just get the same error.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// global variables
// these must be changed depending on the file.
const int SIZE = 10; // num of students
const int AMOUNTOFGRADES = 5; // num of tests per student
ifstream input;


// function declarations
void readInName();
float calculateAvgAndGrade(int count);
void header();
int readInGrades(int);

int main(){
    header();
    readInName();
    return 0;
    
}

void readInName(){
    string name[SIZE] = {""};
    input.open("grade.txt");
    int row,column;
    int count;

    for(row = 0; row < SIZE; row++){
        input >> name[row];
        cout << setw(10) << name[row] << ": ";
        count = readInGrades(row);
        cout << setw(5) << calculateAvgAndGrade(count) << endl;
    }
    
    input.close();
}

int readInGrades(int){
    int r,c;
    int grades[SIZE][AMOUNTOFGRADES] = {0};
    int count = 0;

    for(c = 0; c < AMOUNTOFGRADES; c++){
        input >> grades[r][c];
        cout << setw(5) << grades[r][c] << " ";
        count = count + grades[r][c];
    }
    return count;
}

float calculateAvgAndGrade(int count){
    return float(count)/AMOUNTOFGRADES;
}

void header(){
    cout << setw(15) << "     Names    " << setw(20) << "Grades   " << setw(18) << "Avg " << endl;
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(53) << '-' << endl << setfill(' ');
}
```

Comment: Have u add the all headers, I think you are missing `#include <iomanip> #include <iostream>` headers and you have uninitialized var's in function `readInGrades`.

Comment: The array in `readInGrades` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

In readInGrades(), `r` is used uninitialized as an index to write into `grades[r][c]`, which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So `r` may by chance have any value and write to arbitrary locations in memory. This would sometimes corrupt the stack and trigger a segmentation fault. A helpful tool to troubleshoot these kinds of errors is [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), enabled in clang or gcc by compiling with -fsanitize=address, or if you are using Xcode, there is [an option for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_memory_thread_and_crash_issues_early). Another great tool is [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

Comment: You also can use `std::array` instead of raw arrays. In debug builds out of bounds indexes are diagnosed.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the implementation of your standard library may do bounds checking in debug builds but that isn't necessarily true in all cases. Looks like the OP is on Linux and presumably therefore using libstdc++ which doesn't generally come with a debug version

Comment: @AlanBirtles you're right, but any sane modern implementation probably does bounds checking in debug builds, amongst other reasons that's what debug builds are for

Comment: No bounds checks in [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/f56f1a5a755e4f2080ff709ad7bf4088b84faefe/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/array#L54) or [libc++](https://github.com/google/libcxx/blob/27c836ff3a9c505deb9fd1616012924de8ff9279/include/array#L183)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:

input >> grades[r][c];

r - isn't initialized.

Comment: And, there is utility "procdump" from sysinternals for getting dump at segmentation fault and other troubles.